# How can I create a custom keras optimizer?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, optimization, tf.keras

I'm working on comparing the performances of SVRG, SAG and other optimizers for deep learning minimization.

How can I implement custom optimizers with keras, I tried looking at the SGD keras implementation here [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/optimizer_v2/gradient_descent.py) but couldn't find the source code for `tf.raw_ops.ResourceApplyGradientDescent` which makes it difficult to reproduce for another optimizer.

Comment: I think you mean custom optimizer, a costumed optimizer would be something else, like an optimizer in cosplay :)

Answer (score 4):

To customize an optimizer:

- Extend `tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer`.
- Override `_create_slots`: This for creating optimizer variable for each trainable variable. Would be useful if you need to add momentum to your optimizer.
- Override `_resource_apply_dense` or `_resource_apply_sparse` to do the actual update and the equation of your optimizer.
- `get_config` (Optional): store the paramters you pass to the optimizer so that you can clone, or save your model afterwards.

Here is a quick example of SGD with momentum taken from [here](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/12_custom_models_and_training_with_tensorflow.ipynb)

```py
class MyMomentumOptimizer(keras.optimizers.Optimizer):
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.001, momentum=0.9, name="MyMomentumOptimizer", **kwargs):
        """Call super().__init__() and use _set_hyper() to store hyperparameters"""
        super().__init__(name, **kwargs)
        self._set_hyper("learning_rate", kwargs.get("lr", learning_rate)) # handle lr=learning_rate
        self._set_hyper("decay", self._initial_decay) # 
        self._set_hyper("momentum", momentum)
    
    def _create_slots(self, var_list):
        """For each model variable, create the optimizer variable associated with it.
        TensorFlow calls these optimizer variables "slots".
        For momentum optimization, we need one momentum slot per model variable.
        """
        for var in var_list:
            self.add_slot(var, "momentum")

    @tf.function
    def _resource_apply_dense(self, grad, var):
        """Update the slots and perform one optimization step for one model variable
        """
        var_dtype = var.dtype.base_dtype
        lr_t = self._decayed_lr(var_dtype) # handle learning rate decay
        momentum_var = self.get_slot(var, "momentum")
        momentum_hyper = self._get_hyper("momentum", var_dtype)
        momentum_var.assign(momentum_var * momentum_hyper - (1. - momentum_hyper)* grad)
        var.assign_add(momentum_var * lr_t)

    def _resource_apply_sparse(self, grad, var):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def get_config(self):
        base_config = super().get_config()
        return {
            **base_config,
            "learning_rate": self._serialize_hyperparameter("learning_rate"),
            "decay": self._serialize_hyperparameter("decay"),
            "momentum": self._serialize_hyperparameter("momentum"),
        }
```

Comment: Thank you! But I still have some trouble with _resource_apply_dense method. Before, when I had to code optimization algorithms in a different framework than neural networks, I had to loop over a certain number of iterations to update the parameters, and I feel like we're only doing 1 update here.

Comment: Glad it helped, The `_resource_apply_dense` is ran on every batch, the loop you are talking about is implemented within the fit function of keras and not within the optimizer.