# How do I integrate a training process into keras, that is not backpropagation based?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, genetic-algorithm

I am doing machine learning research where I explore non backpropagation options for training neural networks. I have implemented a [genetic algorithm](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-genetic-algorithms-to-train-neural-networks-b5ffe0d51321) for training of keras models but I would like to make some improvements.

Currently I'm training the model by extracting the parameters with `model.get_weights()`, modifying them in a genetic algorithm, and then setting the weights again, with `model.set_weights()`, for loss calculation. This is being done by passing the network to a training function that performs the training and returns a history as such:
`history = genetic_algorithm(model, *args)`.

I would like to act within the keras interface if possible so that I could compile the model using my training function somehow and then simply train with `model.fit()`. Is this possible? I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66646703/how-can-i-create-a-custom-keras-optimizer) post regarding creating custom optimizers but it seems to be to constrained to allow a genetic algorithm.

This question is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69574291/how-can-i-manually-set-parameters-in-a-keras-network-more-efficiently-than-mode) I have asked. I split them up to make each question more concise.