# How can I manually set parameters in a keras network, more efficiently than model.set_weight()?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, genetic-algorithm

I am doing machine learning research where I explore non backpropagation options for training neural networks. I have implemented a [genetic algorithm](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-genetic-algorithms-to-train-neural-networks-b5ffe0d51321) for training of keras models but I would like to make some improvements.

Currently I'm training the model by extracting the parameters with `model.get_weights()`, modifying them in a genetic algorithm, and then setting the weights again, with `model.set_weights()`, for loss calculation. This is being done by passing the network to a training function that performs the training and returns a history as such:
`history = genetic_algorithm(model, *args)`.

When profiling my code, `model.set_weights()` makes up 29% of the code running time. Is there any way I can modify model parameters in a more performance efficient manner?

This question is related to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/keras) I have asked. I split them up to make each question more concise.

EDIT:

Evaluation takes up about 96 % of the time in my algorithm. Nearly all of this time is spent in keras or tensorflow. Evaluation consists of setting network parameters, performing a forward pass through the network, and evaluating the output with a loss function (categorical crossentropy).

`model.set_weights()` makes up 29% of the code running time, as mentioned earlier, so I assume most of the remaining is the forward pass through the network.

Evaluation code:

```
def evaluate_population(population: np.ndarray,
                        model: keras.Model,
                        loss_function,
                        inputs: np.ndarray,
                        target_outputs: np.ndarray,
                        node_indices: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    losses = np.zeros(len(population))
    params = model.get_weights()
    for i in range(len(population)):
        losses[i] = evaluate_chromosome(population[i], model, loss_function, inputs,
                                        target_outputs, params, node_indices)

    return losses
```

```
def evaluate_chromosome(chromosome: np.ndarray,
                        model: keras.Model,
                        loss_function,
                        inputs: np.ndarray,
                        target_outputs: np.ndarray,
                        params: np.ndarray,
                        node_indices: np.ndarray):
    if node_indices is None:
        set_params(model, chromosome, params)
    else:
        set_nbn_params(model, chromosome, params, node_indices)
    predicted_outputs = model(inputs)
    return loss_function(target_outputs, np.squeeze(predicted_outputs.numpy()))
```

```
def set_params(model: keras.Model, chromosome: np.ndarray, dummy_params):
    params = []
    i = 0
    for layer in dummy_params:
        ls = layer.size
        flat_layer = chromosome[i:i+ls]
        i += ls
        params.append(np.reshape(flat_layer, layer.shape))

    model.set_weights(params)
```

Comment: It is not clear if 29% of runtime is a problem or not, depends on how you are calling these functions, including your code would help.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I provided more context and code examples as requested.